# jQGrid getting error Cannot read property 'id' of undefined on production but only when site is visited from US

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

There is something very strange happening with jQGrid.min.js erroring out in the console on a production site.

If I go to the site in the US I get the error: 'Cannot read property 'id' of undefined' in jQgrid.min.js and if I go to the same exact site in India there is no error at all. Same browsers, same versions.

Any thoughts on what this could be from?

Comment: Do you load your data via ajax call? Does it fail?

Comment: Could you describe **exactly** the problem? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), commercial [jqGrid-ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Where is your JavaScript code? Which web browser you used in test?

Comment: You should repeat the test with non-minimized version of jqGrid (`jquery.jqgrid.src.js` or `jquery.jqgrid.js` depend on version which you use) instead of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`. If you open Developer Tools (press F12 to start) or Browser Console you will see the **line number**, where exactly the error "'Cannot read property 'id' of undefined'" take place.